# Threejs render area shrinks to 25% when resizing the renderer

Tags: three.js, webgl

After calling renderer.setSize() a second time after setting up my viewports, my scene appears to shrink to 25% of its original size and move to the lower left side of the canvas. My use case requires calling setSize multiple times, as I would like to have the user able to enter and leave fullscreen mode at will.

I expected this would be a bug in my program, except that I have managed to reproduce it on a number of examples on the web (All of which use viewports).

This one is from the Three.js homepage:
http://i42.tinypic.com/s5a747.jpg

This is from stemkoski.github.io:
http://i42.tinypic.com/313qi5u.png

Because of this, I am not sure if the issue is due to my graphics card, my computer, some unusual setting, or a bug in Three.js. I am using a macbook pro with retina display, Nvidia GeForce GT 650M 1024MB. I have been able to reproduce this both in chrome, and firefox. Oddly enough, if I hook up an external monitor to the computer and drag my window onto that, the issue goes away after refreshing the page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this example http://uihacker.blogspot.gr/2013/03/javascript-antialias-post-processing.html that deals with device pixel ratio (retina display) and apply the dpr to your renderer dimensions and when you resize the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Gaitat said, it's the device pixel ratio (DPR) that changes between standard and retina displays.

However is the viewport size that needs to be adjusted, not the renderer size. This code achieves a 1:1 pixel resolution on Chrome and Firefox in three.js r65:

```
var DPR = (window.devicePixelRatio) ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1;
var WW = window.innerWidth;
var HH = window.innerHeight;
renderer.setSize( WW, HH );        
renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, WW*DPR, HH*DPR );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

There's some [more info on the problem here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2969).

Comment: This fixed this issue on ipads as well as some of our laptops

Answer (score 13):

As of r70 device pixel ratio for renderer can be set via:

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1)
```

Comment: thanks for this! Remember also to set the pixelRatio before the renderer.setSize() if not the pixelRatio will not be used.

Comment: I have been tearing my hair out over a similar problem I've been having and  your answer to this question has solved it, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the renderer, pass in the `devicePixelRatio` option;

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  devicePixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
```

You shouldn't have to set the viewport size manually, I think devicePixelRatio was added to `WebGLRenderer` in r54.